# Drag and drop reordering of table rows with ASP.NET MVC implementation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. On a web page, I have a HTML table presenting a number of items.

I want to be able to implement drag and drop re-ordering for the table of items, which is saved back to the data model.

I've looked at and tried a few different methods for doing this, using JQuery UI and some other plugins but I haven't successfully been able to implement the functionality.

I've looked at [this](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/) example, but my table didn't change on running it after implementing it as follows:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#clueTable tbody').sortable().disableSelection();
        });
    </script>
```

I have all the necessary javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not going to post the whole table, but it looks something like this:

```
        <table id="clueTable" class="grid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Clue #</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Quiz Clue?</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Clues.Count; i++)
        {
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number</td>
                    <td>Things</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Stuff</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: You should post what you have tried and its results. Otherwise this question won't last long.

Comment: http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/

Comment: @BNL I seen this previously. That too suggests that merely invoking sortable() for the table element will allow it to work... but nothing changes on the table when I run the code... I'll show what I have

Comment: There is a jsfiddle linked from that article with a working example.

Comment: Why do you have `tbody` around every `tr`? There should be only one `tbody` (if any).

Comment: I did a Google search on your question and came up with this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331986/Table-Row-Drag-and-Drop-in-ASP-NET-MVC-jQuery-Data

Comment: @BNL That's an error, thanks for spotting. I corrected this and retried running the page to see if that allowed it to work properly.

Comment: This kids, is why you have to post some code. :)

Comment: I think I'm still missing something as it still isn't working. I'll post the full table just to be sure there's something else not right.

Comment: You should leave the broken code in the question. Removing it removes any context for the solution.

Comment: What was a pretty good question in revision 4 is now a mess. Try to recreate your problem with jsfiddle and post the simplest example. I'd suggest rolling this question back to rev 4, where your original problem was solved and opening a new question for whatever you come up with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177584/jquery-ui-sortable-method-not-supported-error New question created (and apologies for the previous mess).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The duplicated `tbody` tags are your problem.

Works:

http://jsfiddle.net/vR9UW/

Doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/vR9UW/1/